# New to ubuntu. Wifi dongle not recognized

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

This morning I installed ubuntu 17.1 dual-boot on a separate hard drive. my windows 8.1 install gets internet through a dongle (netgear wna3100), ubuntu doesn't recognize it. I don't have access to a wired connection; I do have a laptop with wifi so downloading packages via USB is viable.

I do recognize that this question has likely been answered already but I've been unable to get anything to work thus-far. it would be easier if there weren't multiple non-overlapping answers to each question.

I wish there were more specifics I could give, but I have no idea what the problem actually is and I don't want to end up chasing a red herring because I mentioned something irrelevant. If you know what information is needed I'd be happy to give it in as much detail as I can.

Thank you for your patience.

edit too long for comment:

```
user@system:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 40:16:7e:a6:03:29
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
user@system:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0781:5598 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c07d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: In Ubuntu, with the dongle plugged in, `sudo lshw -C network`, `lsusb` would give you more spicifics to share, as would the type of computer you have.

Comment: Please check here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=Wna3100

Comment: Yes I have seen that post before. The first thing it says to do is try `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-dkms ndiswrapper-utils-1.9` which cannot be located. I don't know where to find those packages, I don't know what they do. If I could find them and put them on a flash-drive I wouldn't know how to install them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I didn't think of it before, I don't know why it's not the first thing recommended when searching how to download wifi drivers sans-internet.

I'm using my phone as a wifi-tether. I can follow the instructions from previous forum posts easily enough now. I don't have any specific questions at the moment, so may as well close the thread.

Thank you for you time.